# Word file running an SQL command - How do I find the source SQL database?

Tags: select, ms-access, datafile

A word 2013 file has a merge function that activates whenever this is open and it is "SELECT * FROM 'database'".

As the final results have errors (the final word document feeds from the wrong field names) I would like to edit the database to change a few things.

The problem is I cannot seem to locate the 'database' as it's not in the same folder as the aforementioned Word file.

We use Access 2003 and this code was created by a person that does not work with us anymore.

Is there a way to locate the source database from the Word file (Word 2013, we only use Access for Office 2003)?

Thank you.

Comment: This may be an obvious question, but have you done a search on your systems for a .mdb files?

Comment: hi H.79, we have a huge amount of data and we use plenty of .mdb files for different reasons... so it will be like finding a needle in the hay ^^'... That's why I was wondering if the excel or the word file involved can be used to locate the access source.

Comment: Well, that sucks...... Not to be a jerk, but that really sucks. Do you happen to have an old machine where it used to work. I have a feeling it might be a DSN that's allowing Office to make the connection to the mdb file.

Comment: perhaps the link is in your ODBC data sources. If it's in there, you can find where the data is coming from

Comment: Edit the code-behind and have a look at it. You'll find out the connection string